# using template classes above main giving error during function call in main

Tags: c++

I am using a base class and a child class defined above main in main.cpp
this gives me an error of undefined reference FactoryTraversal::AddPoint::AddPoint(int const&, int const&, int)'
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cmath>

enum traversal_type
{
    TRAVERSAL = 0,
    TRAVERSALMAX
};

template <class T>
class FactoryTraversal
{
public:
    FactoryTraversal();
    FactoryTraversal *CreateInstance(const traversal_type &type);
    virtual ~FactoryTraversal();
    const std::list<int>& GetIndices() const {return indices;}
    int GetIndicesSize() const {return indices.size();}
    virtual void AddPoint(const T &x, const T &y, int index);
protected:
    std::list<int> indices;
};

template<class T>
class Traversal : public FactoryTraversal<T>
{
public:
    Traversal();
    void AddPoint(const T &x, const T &y, int index);
    int GetResultXOR() const {return result_xor;}
private:
    T coords_s[2];
    T coords_e[2];
    int result_xor;
    void update_result(int index);
    T calculate_distance(const T &x1, const T &x2, const T &y1, const T &y2);
};
template<class T>
Traversal<T>::Traversal():FactoryTraversal<T>()
{
    //Do nothing
}
template<class T>
void Traversal<T>::AddPoint(const T &x, const T &y, int index)
{
    if (0 == this->GetIndicesSize())
    {
        this->indices.push_front(index);
        coords_s[0] = x; coords_s[1] = y;
        coords_e[0] = x; coords_e[1] = y;
    }
    else
    {
        T d1 = this->calculate_distance(x,coords_s[0],y,coords_s[1]);
        T d2 = this->calculate_distance(x,coords_e[0],y,coords_e[1]);
        if (d1 < d2)
        {
            this->indices.push_front(index);
            coords_s[0] = x; coords_s[1] = y;
        }
        else
        {
            this->indices.push_back(index);
            coords_e[0] = x; coords_e[1] = y;
        }
    }
    this->update_result(index);
}
template<class T>
T Traversal<T>::calculate_distance(const T &x1, const T &x2, const T &y1, const T &y2)
{
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(int))
    {
        return std::min(std::abs(x1-x2),std::abs(y1-y2));
    }
    return 0;
}
template<class T>
void Traversal<T>::update_result(int index)
{
    if (0 == this->GetIndicesSize())
        result_xor = index;
    else
        result_xor ^= index;
}
template<class T>
FactoryTraversal<T>::FactoryTraversal()
{
    indices.clear();
}
template<class T>
FactoryTraversal<T>::~FactoryTraversal()
{
    //Do Nothing
}
template<class T>
FactoryTraversal<T>* FactoryTraversal<T>::CreateInstance(const traversal_type &type)
{
    if (TRAVERSAL == type)
        return new Traversal<T>();
    else
        return NULL;
}

FactoryTraversal<int> factory_traversal;
Traversal<int> *traversal = new Traversal<int>();

int main()
{
    int T;
    std::cin>>T;
    int output[T];
    for (int i = 0; i < T; ++i)
    {
        int N;
        std::cin>>N;
        FactoryTraversal<int> factory_traversal;
        FactoryTraversal<int> *traversal = factory_traversal.CreateInstance(TRAVERSAL);
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            int x, y;
            std::cin>>x>>y;
            traversal->AddPoint(x,y,j+1);
        }
        Traversal<int> *tmp = dynamic_cast<Traversal<int> *>(traversal);
        if (tmp)
            output[i] = tmp->GetResultXOR();
        else
            output[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < T; ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<output[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: AddPoint should be pure virtual in the base class.

Comment: Possible problem(s): `FactoryTraversal<int> *traversal = factory_traversal.CreateInstance(TRAVERSAL);` in main is shadowing a global; `factory_traversal` in main is also shadowing. Also `error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'output'`

Comment: You never defined `virtual void AddPoint(const T &x, const T &y, int index);`

Comment: @NathanOliver More specifically, `FactoryTraversal::AddPoint`. There is an implementation for `Traversal<T>::AddPoint`.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces in C++ are called ["abstract classes"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class), and classes are abstract if they have at least one "pure virtual function". A  function is a pure virtual function if it is prefixed with `virtual` and has a trailing `=0` in its declaration. This is what you want for `FactoryTraversal::AddPoint`:

```
virtual void AddPoint(const T &x, const T &y, int index) = 0;
```

Now the derived class is expected to define it (and it does). Without `AddPoint` being pure virtual, you are forced to provide an implementation for it in the base class, which you could do simply as:

```
virtual void AddPoint(const T &x, const T &y, int index){}
```

This gives a "default" or fallback implementation for when a derived class chooses not to override the method. If it were pure virtual, the derived class is *forced* to define it, lest a call to it result in a compiler error (otherwise the derived class is also considered abstract).

Note that destructors should never be pure virtual. The way you have it right now is great; you unconsciously followed the rules I've outlined above.

#### Some other notes:

- Variable length arrays are not legal C++, this is a compiler extension:

  `int output[T]; // T is read from command line`

Use a [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
 std::vector<int> output(T);
```

- You have memory leaks as-is. Use a managed pointer like [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) so you don't have to worry about `new` and `delete`
- I stated that you wanted `AddPoint` to be pure virtual and I mean it. You code won't compile if that's the first step you take, though. It looks like you merged a base class and a factory into one; split those out.

Putting it all together we can define our new base class as:

```
template<class T>
class TraversalBase
{
public:
    virtual ~TraversalBase(){}
    const std::list<int>& GetIndices() const {return indices;}
    int GetIndicesSize() const {return indices.size();}
    virtual void AddPoint(const T &x, const T &y, int index) = 0;
protected:
    std::list<int> indices; 
};
```

The derived class becomes (very little change, also notice the [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) keyword):

```
template<class T>
class Traversal : public TraversalBase<T>
{
public:
    void AddPoint(const T &x, const T &y, int index) override;
    int GetResultXOR() const {return result_xor;}
private:
    T coords_s[2];
    T coords_e[2];
    int result_xor;
    void update_result(int index);
    T calculate_distance(const T &x1, const T &x2, const T &y1, const T &y2);
};
```

And our Factory class is much simplified:

```
template <class T>
struct FactoryTraversal
{
    FactoryTraversal(){}
    std::unique_ptr<TraversalBase<T>> CreateInstance(const traversal_type &type);
    ~FactoryTraversal(){}
};
```

### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3GOBXjTqBzpjLPvL) (C++11)